# Status bar cover action bar in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-statusbar

I want my status bar to be transparent and match action bar color. But for different activities I have diffenrent color for action bar so I can't use "**colorPrimaryDark**" for my status bar. How to achive this?

**v21\styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Activities has "**android:fitsSystemWindows="false"**"

This is what I have
[image]
And this is what I want
[image]

Same for other colors in action bar.

Any help?

Comment: `Activities has "android:fitsSystemWindows="false""` why?

Comment: If "android:fitsSystemWindows="true"" then status bar is transporent and white color behind it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the normal behavior - this command is for use cases when you want a picture that can't be stretched out behind the status bar like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30882429/6028746).
**Solution-**

1. In my opinion from the picture just change the status bar color:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/Red</item>
```

2. Increase the height of your action bar by 25dp (status bar height).

Comment: 1. Change status bar color for every activity?

2. I can't increase height in layout file because for defferent screen size status bar height is different

Comment: 1. will work fine for all activities because for all activities if you use one theme in your app and if not you can inherit your seems from app seem with the "android:statusBarColor" inside.
2. Also works for all handset devices because it's **dp** (Change size with relation to the device). @Ossir